# What causes "Value cannot be negative" in cloudwatch agent logs?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I see the following log entries in `/var/log/amazon/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.log`

```
2021-10-06T13:18:00Z W! Value cannot be negative: -1
2021-10-06T13:18:00Z W! Value cannot be negative: -1
2021-10-06T13:18:00Z W! Value cannot be negative: -1
```

Is there anyway to find out what is the source of  this `-1` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a good way to find the actual source in the general case. That's why I opened [an issue in aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/issues/288).

But there are some guesses that you can do:

**First**, check if you are using collectd GenericJMX to collect the `NonHeapMemoryUsage` attribute from `java.lang:type=Memory` MBean, that is part of the [usual collectd's GenericJMX example configuration](https://git.octo.it/?p=collectd.git;a=blob;f=contrib/GenericJMX.conf;hb=master#l122). The `NonHeapMemoryUsage` is a composite attribute with `committed`,`init`, `max` and `used`. And `max` is **always -1**.

You can verify this using jmx-term cli utility:

```
java -jar jmxterm-1.0.2-uber.jar
$>open localhost:8993
$>get -d java.lang -b java.lang:type=Memory NonHeapMemoryUsage
#mbean = java.lang:type=Memory:
NonHeapMemoryUsage = {
  committed = 312860672;
  init = 7667712;
  max = -1;
  used = 304634560;
 };
```

If this is the case you can use collectd [Chains](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Chains) functionality to "drop" the `TypeInstance=nonheap-max`, by adding the following to your collectd.conf:

```
<Chain "PostCache">
  # only show system and user
  <Rule "jmx_memory">
    <Match "regex">
      Plugin "GenericJMX"
      Type "jmx_memory"
    </Match>


    <Match "regex">
    TypeInstance "nonheap-max"
    Invert true
    </Match>

    # If a jmx_memory metric and it's not the nonheap-max then send it to the amazon-cloudwatch-agent 25826
    <Target "write"> 
      Plugin network
    </Target>
  </Rule>

  # Default target drop all metrics
  Target "stop"
</Chain>
```

**Second**, if it not the `NonHeapMemoryUsage` is likely to be any other collectd metric, you can drop all metrics with negative values with [collectd's <Match "Value">](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Match:Value) although I **don't recommend it**:

```
<Chain "PostCache">
  # only show system and user
  <Rule "drop negative">
    <Match "value">
         Min 0
         Satisfy "All"
         
    </Match>


    # send positive values to  amazon-cloudwatch-agent 25826
    <Target "write"> 
      Plugin network
    </Target>
  </Rule>

  # Default target drop all metrics
  Target "stop"
</Chain>
```